# How to properly align elements in center?

Tags: html, css

I have simple `grid`, created with `css`

```
#videowall-grid{
    width:700px; 
    border:1px dotted #dddddd;
    display: none; 
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px;
}

 #videowall-grid .square{
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px dashed #dddddd;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;

    <div id="videowall-grid" style="display: block;"><div class="row">
<div id="1_1" class="square">8</div><div id="1_2" class="square">373</div><div id="1_3" class="square">1</div><div id="1_4" class="square">111</div></div><div class="row">
<div id="2_1" class="square">318</div><div id="2_2" class="square">319</div><div id="2_3" class="square">321</div><div id="2_4" class="square">button</div></div><div class="row">
<div id="3_1" class="square">234</div><div id="3_2" class="square">button</div><div id="3_3" class="square">button</div><div id="3_4" class="square">button</div></div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/upHjg/

So how to `center` text inside squares and squares inside parent `div`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `text-align:center;` style to `#videowall-grid`:

```
#videowall-grid{
    width:700px; 
    border:1px dotted #dddddd;
    display: none; 
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

`text-align` can be used to align any `inline` elements. Since you set your `.square`s to `inline-block` they react to this style.

Check this [JSFiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/upHjg/1/)

P.S. The text *is* centered inside their squares in your JSfiddle.

Comment: Thats kind of a different question, but adding `vertical-align:top;` to your squares should work. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upHjg/3/)

Comment: @Kirix you can try using disply:table and table-cell as mentioned in my answer. that goes with long text also

Comment: but text still in the top... May be possible somehow with overflow in squares??? O just return to tables?

Comment: Is the question that you originally asked not answered? If you have a question about something else, you should ask another question, not just comment it here.

Answer (score 2):

Add `display:table` & `margin:0 auto` to row div ***and*** `display:table-cell` to get the text vertically middle

```
#videowall-grid{
    width:700px; 
    border:1px dotted #dddddd;
    display: none; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px; text-align:center
}
#row{display:table;  margin:0 auto}
 #videowall-grid .square{
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px dashed #dddddd;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle
}​
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jARnw/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align: center;` in `#videowall-grid` it will solve your problem.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mbilal/ArU57/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="videowall-grid" style="display: block;" align="center">
```

modify this div like above

Answer (score 0):

Adding paddig will dot the work for you. Try this edited code. Here I have edited padding in the videowall-grid and also in the .square also

```
<style type="text/css">
#videowall-grid{
    width:550px; 
    border:1px dotted #dddddd;
    display: none; 
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 150px;

}

 #videowall-grid .square{
    padding: 30px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px dashed #dddddd;
    width: 70px;
    height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<div id="videowall-grid" style="display: block;"><div class="row">
<div id="1_1" class="square">8</div><div id="1_2" class="square">373</div><div id="1_3" class="square">1</div><div id="1_4" class="square">111</div></div><div class="row">
<div id="2_1" class="square">318</div><div id="2_2" class="square">319</div><div id="2_3" class="square">321</div><div id="2_4" class="square">button</div></div><div class="row">
<div id="3_1" class="square">234</div><div id="3_2" class="square">button</div><div id="3_3" class="square">button</div><div id="3_4" class="square">button</div></div></div>
```